# Skip trimming CRC from packet

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, libpcap, crc

I have a application in linux, Where i expect comeplete packet including last 4 CRC Checksum bytes. In my case Linux kernel is trimming off the CRC Checksum and sending to my application. Is there any way in Linux to disable trimming CRC Checksum??

Comment: Show us your code! Normally you would never see any of the surrounding IP packet in user space. This is possible to change, but a rare thing to do.

Comment: I have retrived packets using pcap library

Comment: You may be able to use raw sockets to handle the packets yourself if the network layer you're interested in is level 4 or above in the OSI model (e.g. TCP or UDP).

Comment: Hi tanfrs,
Actually I am intrested in complete packet (including ethernet frame)